# Open default File Manager External Memory in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent

Our Android devices contains Internal Memory and External Memory. Our Application contains one Open Button. When we have click this Open Button to View/Open Default File Manager External Memory.

Sample Code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("file/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "View Default File Manager"));
```

This code can be Viewd/Opened Default File Manager Internal Memory.

How do (Click an Open Button to) View/Open Default File Manager External Memory?

Is it Possible?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/file");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),”application/file”);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Vishwa Thanks for Responses. Unfortunately this code is not working for me.

Answer (score -1):

In class definitions:

```
public static String SDCARD_DIRECTORY;
public static String REPORTS_DIRECTORY;
```

In onCreate:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
SDCARD_DIRECTORY = sdCard.getAbsolutePath();
REPORTS_DIRECTORY = SDCARD_DIRECTORY + "/MyReports";
// Create if necessary the desired folder
File directory = new File (REPORTS_DIRECTORY);
directory.mkdirs();
```

Now, this code is working for me.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
File file = new File(REPORTS_DIRECTORY);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),"application/file");
StartActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Open folder"), 0);
```